# Could not build Application in the simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

when trying to run my ios application on my Iphone 15 Pro Max simulator, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error (Xcode): Sandbox: rsync.samba(44106) deny(1) file-write-create
/Users/mustafa/Desktop/flutter_starter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework


Error (Xcode): Sandbox: dart(44085) deny(1) file-write-create
/Users/mustafa/Desktop/flutter_starter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/.last_build_id


Error (Xcode): Flutter failed to write to a file at
"/Users/mustafa/Desktop/flutter_starter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/.last_build_id".
```

There are no erros in my code and flutter doctor shows no errors as well:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.14.0-14.0.pre.362, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-TZ)
    • Flutter version 3.14.0-14.0.pre.362 on channel master at /Users/mustafa/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5b47fef613 (2 weeks ago), 2023-09-19 15:49:57 -0400
    • Engine revision 28f14e6eec
    • Dart version 3.2.0 (build 3.2.0-179.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.28.0-dev.8

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mustafa/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A240d
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.74.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile) • C6431A06-5012-47C7-AFDE-B522E40E339B • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.0
      23A344 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google
      Chrome 117.0.5938.132
```

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!